# Json not encode my Special Character

Tags: php, json, curl

My database table have these two fields:

Title = Testing Title
Description = CREDITO FISCAL OCDE CFDI AMPAROS REVISIÓN ELECTRÓNICA REGLAMENTO ISR RIF
ID: 44

And my json response always returning me with null description. I noticed json unable to encode this character [ Ó ] ?

```
[
    {
        "title":"Testing Title",
        "description":null,
        "id":"44"
    }
]
```

Can someone please help ?

Here how i encode the json array

echo json_encode($response);

Comment: `json_encode()` only works with utf-8, surely you have an encoding problem. Where comes the input from, and what encoding are you using (input and output)

Comment: when i display the description directly it works fine but return null with json.

Comment: can you add `echo json_last_error_msg();` after your `json_encode()` and    show us the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example will make things a little clearer:

```
<?php

$dbData = [[
    "title" => "Testing Title",
    "description" => "REDITO FISCAL OCDE CFDI AMPAROS REVISIÓN ELECTRÓNICA REGLAMENTO ISR RIF",
    "id" => 44
]];

$dbDataUTF8 = array_map("utf8_encode", $dbData[0]);

echo json_encode($dbDataUTF8, true);
?>
```

Depending on the encoding of your `$dbData` this code will output something like this:

```
[{"title":"Testing Title","description":"REDITO FISCAL OCDE CFDI AMPAROS REVISI\u00c3\u0093N ELECTR\u00c3\u0093NICA REGLAMENTO ISR RIF","id":"44"}]
```

or this:

```
[{"title":"Testing Title","description":"REDITO FISCAL OCDE CFDI AMPAROS REVISI\u00d3N ELECTR\u00d3NICA REGLAMENTO ISR RIF","id":44}]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes but my point is my database table have data in description when i parse it with json is simply rerun me null instead of Description Text that is already in database

Comment: Great it works for me.
One question when i decode the json responsive how do i remove this character ?
For Example: \u etc

Comment: You do not have to do anything special. In PHP, you just need to use `json_decode()` and it converts everything correctly. In Javascript you do not need to anything special either. Just do your `JSON.parse(yourJsonString)` and it will convert everything fine.

Comment: i am parsing it in android does it will work the same ?

Comment: If you are using this in a browser on Android-devices, as long as that browser can run `jQuery` and knows the `JSON`-object you should be fine. In short: Yes, shouldn't be a problem and will work the same.